# Woocommerce: clear the cart when order status changes to Processing

Tags: woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I need to clear the cart when order status changes to Processing. I mean to clear the cart for the **customer who made the order**.

I've got to create this function:

```
add_action('woocommerce_order_status_processing','force_clear_the_cart');
function force_clear_the_cart(){
    global $woocommerce;
    $woocommerce->cart->empty_cart();
}
```

But I think that this function will clear the cart for the user who update the Order (the shop manager user) and not for the user who made the order (the customer).

Am I right? If so, how can I fetch the user/customer and clear its cart?

Comment: When a customer placed an order cart will automatically empty. this is the default behaviour of woocommerce.

Comment: @Bhautik I know but somehow sometime the cart is not cleared. That's is why I need to force to clear the cart.

Comment: You can use the `woocommerce_thankyou` hook.